# Best way to play an audio with expo-av?

Tags: react-native, audio, expo, expo-av

After a lot of testing with expo-av in a development build I can't find a way to play an audio efficiently.

Here are my 3 different ways, what's should be the better one and why?
I'm having the "Player doesn't exist" error sometimes and after no more sounds are played...
[This this GitHub thread](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1873)

In the first example the "audioRef" is defined as:

```
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

const soundPath= require('sound.mp3');
const soundRef = useRef(new Audio.Sound());
soundRef.current.loadAsync(soundPath, {}); // {} = empty options

export const PlayAudio = async (audioRef, fromStart = true) => {
  try {
    const result = await audioRef.current.getStatusAsync();
    if (result.isLoaded) {
      if (result.isPlaying === false) {
        if (fromStart) {
          audioRef.current.playFromPositionAsync(0);
        } else {
          audioRef.current.playAsync();
        }
      } else if (fromStart) {
        audioRef.current.pauseAsync();
        audioRef.current.playFromPositionAsync(0);
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error playing Audio : ', e);
  }
};
```

The two next examples take a "requiredPath" parameter which is just something like:

`const requiredPath = require('sound.mp3')`

```
export const PlayAudioBis = async (requiredPath, options = {}) => {
  // LOAD
  const sound = new Audio.Sound();
  try {
    await sound.loadAsync(requiredPath, options);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error Loading Audio : ', e);
  }

  // PLAY
  try {
    const result = await sound.getStatusAsync();
    if (result.isLoaded) {
      await sound.playAsync();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error playing Audio : ', e);
  }

  // UNLOAD
  try {
    await sound.unloadAsync();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error unlaoding Audio : ', e);
  }
};

export const PlayAudioTer = (requiredPath) => {
  Audio.Sound.createAsync(requiredPath, { shouldPlay: true })
    .then((res) => {
      res.sound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate((status) => {
        if (!status.didJustFinish) {
          return;
        }
        res.sound.unloadAsync().catch((e) => {
          console.error('Error unloading Audio : ', e);
        });
      });
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error('Error creating Audio : ', e);
    });
};
```